# Dockerfile struggling to install Python Geopandas module

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I have a dockerfile in which I am trying to build a container with my required python modules from.

See my dockerfile below to understand how and what modules I am trying to install:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV ROOTDIR /usr/local/
ENV GDAL_VERSION 2.4.1
ENV OPENJPEG_VERSION 2.3.0
ENV CURL_CA_BUNDLE /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Load assets
WORKDIR $ROOTDIR/

ADD http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/${GDAL_VERSION}/gdal-${GDAL_VERSION}.tar.gz $ROOTDIR/src/
ADD https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/archive/v${OPENJPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz $ROOTDIR/src/openjpeg-${OPENJPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz

# Install basic dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    build-essential \
    python-dev \
    python3-dev \
    python-numpy \
    python3-numpy \
    python3-pyproj \
    libspatialite-dev \
    sqlite3 \
    libpq-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libproj-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    libnetcdf-dev \
    libpoppler-dev \
    libspatialite-dev \
    libhdf4-alt-dev \
    libhdf5-serial-dev \
    bash-completion \
    cython \
    cmake

# Compile and install OpenJPEG
RUN cd src && tar -xvf openjpeg-${OPENJPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && cd openjpeg-${OPENJPEG_VERSION}/ \
    && mkdir build && cd build \
    && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROOTDIR \
    && make && make install && make clean \
    && cd $ROOTDIR && rm -Rf src/openjpeg*

# Compile and install GDAL
RUN cd src && tar -xvf gdal-${GDAL_VERSION}.tar.gz && cd gdal-${GDAL_VERSION} \
    && ./configure --with-python --with-spatialite --with-pg --with-curl --with-openjpeg \
    && make -j $(nproc) && make install && ldconfig \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && cd $ROOTDIR && cd src/gdal-${GDAL_VERSION}/swig/python \
    && python3 setup.py build \
    && python3 setup.py install \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge build-essential \
      python-dev \
      python3-dev \
    && cd $ROOTDIR && rm -Rf src/gdal*


# install Vim
RUN apt-get -y install vim

# Install Pip3 and required python modules
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip

RUN pip3 install rasterio &&\
    pip3 install rdp &&\
    pip3 install gdal2tiles&&\
    pip3 install awscli &&\
    pip3 install pandas &&\
    pip3 install boto3 &&\
    pip3 install requests &&\
    pip3 install shapely &&\
    pip3 install geopandas &&\   
    pip3 install math
```

However, it seems to get as far as the geopandas module and then I hit this error:

```
Collecting pyproj>=2.2.0 (from geopandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/12/7a8cca32506747c05ffd5c6ba556cf8435754af0939906cbcc7fa5802ea3/pyproj-3.0.1.tar.gz (168kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Cython.Build.cythonize not found. Cython is required to build pyproj.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vtfufrfs/pyproj/
```

Has anyone any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cython.Build.cythonize+not+found.+Cython+is+required+to+build+pyproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python3 environment is missing the Cython package. Add the line `pip3 install cython` before the `pip3 install geopandas` line.

You will need to upgrade your *pip* version as well.
And it is more convenient to use *pip* directly from the Python3 interpreter rather than the *pip3* wrapper. So I will go to refactor your last `RUN` block like so:

```
RUN \
   python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
   && python3 -m pip install \
        cython \
        rasterio \
        rdp \
        gdal2tiles \
        awscli \
        pandas \
        boto3 \
        requests \
        shapely \
        geopandas
```

Comment: I've tried that and the next error is now ```Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    proj executable not found. Please set the PROJ_DIR variable. For more information see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html```

Comment: @hello_12039 check my updated response.

Comment: Even with your updated response, I am back to the original error message of ```Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Cython.Build.cythonize not found. Cython is required to build pyproj```

Comment: @hello_12039 my bad the pip ugrade should be executed in separated command. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in your dockerfile

```
RUN wget http://download.osgeo.org/libspatialindex/spatialindex-src-1.8.5.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf spatialindex-src-1.8.5.tar.gz && \
  cd spatialindex-src-1.8.5 && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make install && \
  cd - && \
  rm -rf spatialindex-src-1.8.5* && \
  ldconfig

### Install rtree and geopandas
RUN pip install rtree geopandas
```